# Color different from the value set in the xml

Tags: android, xml

I have set the color e.g: `#252525` and in Android Studio preview, it's looking good, but when I run it on my device, the color looks very different from what I chose.  What is the reason?
Is it because my android device is lollipop?
Is it because I'm using Android Studio?
It never happened to me before.
please help me

Comment: its probably because of your screen

Comment: no. i checked it. i'm sure what color i picked.

Comment: Please show the code where you are using this color. Then, please post a screenshot showing what you are seeing. You may need to upload the screenshot elsewhere and link to it from your question.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't post images yet. but believe me i'm working a lot with design. this is not the color i picked. i check it with many screens

Comment: @mattmatt colors can look different on different types of screens, unless you are talking about 252525 color coming up as red or something not even close to that color

Comment: @mattmatt you may not be able to post images on here but you can post links to images that are hosted else where

Comment: Can you describe what you are seeing on your screen and how you know it is not correct?

Comment: I set the color to light gray and after i compile it to my device its looks very dark gray. Significant difference e.g `#d3d3d3` after compile looks `#7d7d7d`

Comment: Silly question, but is your screen brightness turned up?

Comment: "this is not the color i picked" -- that's fine, but **we** cannot see the color, just as **we** cannot see your code where you indicate that you are applying this color. Your job, when you have code that is not working, is to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that perhaps **we** can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your device may have a different color saturation, or it could be the device's screen itself malfunctioning. Try different devices/emulators to try to narrow down what's going wrong.